# Physics2D overlap not working and problem with player positioning

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, game-physics

as you can see in the video, I create a grid using individual tiles. All the tiles are children of the tile-container and the tile-container has a layout grid element so, everything is done automatically (cell size is set up to 45). Here comes the first problem, as you can see, I do not know how to spawn the player exactly in the middle of the selected tile (I will be spawning walls, enemies, etc. in the future), there is a little offset. The second and the main problem is, that the player should not be able to walk into the wall, there is a ray cast (as you can see in the code below) that should check if there is some collider in the way and prevent the player from moving. But he just hits the wall for some reason. Any help would be appreciated.

**Video:**
[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jcge_mBVaP4)

**Player movement (parent is set up to tiles-container, it is called when spawning the player and the player and also the wall has ignore layout element and the wall has stopMovement layer obviously):**

```
public void SetParent(GameObject gb)
    {
        point.parent = gb.transform;
    }
 
    void Update()
    {
        transform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.localPosition, point.localPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);
 
        if ((transform.localPosition - point.localPosition).sqrMagnitude <= .05f && canMove)
        {
            if (!Physics2D.OverlapCircle(point.localPosition + new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * 45, 0f, 0f), .2f, stopMovement))
            {
 
                if (Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")) == 1f)
                {
                    point.localPosition += new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * 45, 0f, 0f);
                }
 
            }
 
            if (!Physics2D.OverlapCircle(point.localPosition + new Vector3(0f, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * 45, 0f), .2f, stopMovement))
            {
 
                if (Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")) == 1f)
                {
                    point.localPosition += new Vector3(0f, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * 45, 0f);
                }
 
            }
 
        }
 
    }
```

**Player prefab:**
[image: Player prefab]

Comment: Where’s the raycast or is this not related to the title?

Comment: Yeah sorry I wrote the wrong title